# How to display temp and percentage symbol next to dynamic value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-knob

I have 2 questions here.

1. How to display Temperature symbol inside the Knob next to dynamic value.
2. How to display Percentage (%) symbol inside the Knob next to dynamic value.

I am using `<input>` tag and Knob JS.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress-box text-center">
    <input type="text" class="knob temperature" data-width="120" data-height="120" data-thickness="0.40" data-fgColor="#000000" readonly>
    <h5 class="text-light-blue padding-top-10 weight-500">Temperature</h5>
</div>

<div class="progress-box text-center">
    <input type="text" class="knob water_level"  data-width="120" data-height="120" data-thickness="0.40" data-fgColor="#000000" readonly>
    <h5 class="text-light-blue padding-top-10 weight-500">Water Level</h5>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.temperature').knob();
$('.temperature').attr('data-fgColor', '#11E117');

$.get(('assets/summary/temperature.php'),  // url
     function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  // success callback
         console.log(data);
         $({animatedVal: 0}).animate({animatedVal: data}, {
         duration: 3000,
         easing: "swing",
         step: function() {
             var val = Math.ceil(this.animatedVal);
             $(".temperature").trigger('configure', {
             'fgColor': colors[(val < 40) ? 0 : (val < 70) ? 1 : 2]
             }).val(val).trigger("change");
             return val + '%';      // I tried to apply this but not happen
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback, user below already my question No 2. However, do you have any idea about my Question No 1? How to display temperature symbol. I have try with '&#8451;' but not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the string in `var val = Math.ceil(this.animatedVal);` instead? Like this: `var val = Math.ceil(this.animatedVal) + ' %';` then just return `val`;

EDITED TO THIS:

try replacing `return val + '%';` with `var newVal = val + ' %'; $('.temperature').val(newVal);` instead .

For adding temp symbol, instead of `&#8451;`, try adding `String.fromCharCode(176)`
like this: `val + String.fromCharCode(176);`

Comment: var val = Math.ceil(this.animatedVal) + ' %';
                $(".temperature").trigger('configure', {
                'fgColor': colors[(val < 40) ? 0 : (val < 70) ? 1 : 2]
                }).val(val).trigger("change");
                return val;

Comment: try replacing  return val + '%'; with
var newVal = val + ' %';
 $('.temperature').val(newVal); instead

Comment: perfect!, Thank You, maybe you can edit your answer above with proper code, so it able for anyone easy to refer later.

Comment: do you have any idea about my Question No 1? How to display temperature symbol. I have try with '&#8451;' but not appear.